# How to zoom image in alert dialog

Tags: android, image, zooming, alert

I developed some application which contain thumbnail pictures of item, if I click then will be displayed alert dialog which display some pictures of it, my question is : is it possible for me to zoom with on touch listener on alert dialog ? I have developed zooming image with touch listener, and it is successfully. Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Create a custom Dialog and if there is only one image than use a `OnTouchListener` and apply the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` where you can scale your image on fling, or use gallery if you have multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom Dialog and do it

Here is the link which will get you to the tutorial about how to do this...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog